# shell script : appending directory path and filename

Tags: linux, shell

I want to copy a file from a directory using shell script

Suppose I save the directory and file name seperately as

```
dir=/home/user/directory/
file=file_1
```

to copy the file Im using this command in my script

```
cp $dir$file .
```

But I get this error

```
/bin/cp omitting directory '/home/user/directory'
```

I have tried all combination eg. omitted the trail backslah from variable dir, etc but nothings working. I cant understand what is wrong with this code. Pleas help

Maybe the command `$dir$file` is not getting unpacked in the shell (ie only the directory variable is getting unpacked, not the file variable)!!!!!

Comment: Debug your script using `bash -xv`, you will see how the variables get expanded. Also, quote you variables to account for whitespace in paths and avoid globbing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are having problem with expansion in `cp $dir$file .` In order to prevent possible problems, it is better to protect your variable with braces and double quote the full path/file to make sure you don't get caught by spaces in either the filename or heaven forbid the user's dirname:

```
cp "${dir}${file}" .
```

This will prevent the possibility the second `$` is missed. Also make sure you have read access to other users /home (if you are root or using sudo you should be fine)

Comment: In the terminal root] pwd=`pwd` root]file=input.txt root] echo $pwd$file        But in the script this doesnt work . What is the reason. I tried your suggestion cp "${dir}${file}" . , but that doesnt work either.

Comment: Ah, in the script, if you are using the `pwd` command you will need to assign the variable as `dir="$(pwd)"` and `file="input.text"` making sure to double-quote (to prevent spaces, etc.). In you script, add `set -x` at the top (below #!/bin/bash) to debug (it will show what is assigned to each variable as it is used)

Answer (score 0):

If you see this, when you somehow assign an empty string to `file` somewhere. Search your script for `file=` and `unset file`.

You can also debug this by adding

```
echo ".${file}."
```

in the line before the `cp` command. I'm pretty sure it prints `..`, i.e. the variable is empty or doesn't exist.

Comment: Aaron, I suspect you are correct about the empty file. From the question with `file=file_1` it made it look like a rock-solid assignment. It was hard to see how `$file` wouldn't be expanded, but after the last comment I got, I suspect the assignment to `file` never took place.